# Python/Pandas - How to iterate through rows of a csv data frame in one column, in order to change the values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I'm reading a csv file using pandas, the file has 5 columns and 7,000 rows. The column names are:

```
df.columns=['agent_name', 'case_id', 'case_type', 'case_subtype', regional_team']
```

I would like to iterate through each row of the column `agent_name`. If the value in that column matches a name in the `regional_team` list, then I would like to add the regional team that corresponds to each agent's name into the `regional_team` column.

The `regional_team` column currently has `NaN` values as a placeholder until I figure out how add a regional team for each agent.

So for example, if the value in the `agent_name` column is `John Smith` then assign `EUR` to the `regional_team` column for that row.

I tried to establish lists to assign agent names to regional lists so that I could reference the lists in my loop statement, but I can't figure out the best way to get this to work in python.

```
latam_team = ['Jose Gonzales', Jennifer Pasale', 'Lorena Lorenzo']
eur_team = ['John Smith', 'Alaister Mckinney', Victoria Norton']
nam_team = ['Jenny Rivera', 'Jacob White', 'Emma Tilman']
```

Regional team nomenclatures which I would like to assign to the `regional_team` column are:

```
['LATAM', 'ASPAC', 'EUR', 'NAM']
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a dictionary to hold the list of names, and use the dictionary keys
as the values to be replaced in the `regional_team` column. You can then use Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
command over the `agent_name` column to check if the name is present `in` the dictionary.

*Setup example.csv*

```py
          agent_name  case_id case_type case_subtype  regional_team
0  Alaister Mckinney     1690     type0     subtype4            NaN
1    George Harrison     1717     type0     subtype2            NaN
2        John Lennon     1389     type0     subtype2            NaN
3        Jacob White     1540     type3     subtype1            NaN
4       Jenny Rivera     1261     type2     subtype0            NaN
5        John Lennon     1302     type4     subtype4            NaN
6        Emma Tilman     1826     type4     subtype4            NaN
7    Jennifer Pasale     1044     type0     subtype1            NaN
8         John Smith     1088     type0     subtype1            NaN
9    Victoria Norton     1162     type2     subtype4            NaN
```

*Code*

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

agents = {
    'LATAM' : ['Jose Gonzales', 'Jennifer Pasale', 'Lorena Lorenzo'],
    'EUR' : ['John Smith', 'Alaister Mckinney', 'Victoria Norton'],
    'NAM' : ['Jenny Rivera', 'Jacob White', 'Emma Tilman'],
    'ASPAC' : ['John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison'],
}

def set_team_name(agent_name):
    for name_reg, name_list in agents.items():
        if agent_name in name_list:
            return name_reg

df ['regional_team'] = df['agent_name'].apply(set_team_name)
print(df)
```

```py
          agent_name  case_id case_type case_subtype regional_team
0  Alaister Mckinney     1690     type0     subtype4           EUR
1    George Harrison     1717     type0     subtype2         ASPAC
2        John Lennon     1389     type0     subtype2         ASPAC
3        Jacob White     1540     type3     subtype1           NAM
4       Jenny Rivera     1261     type2     subtype0           NAM
5        John Lennon     1302     type4     subtype4         ASPAC
6        Emma Tilman     1826     type4     subtype4           NAM
7    Jennifer Pasale     1044     type0     subtype1         LATAM
8         John Smith     1088     type0     subtype1           EUR
9    Victoria Norton     1162     type2     subtype4           EUR
```

Comment: Thank you @n1colas.m AMAZING, this works perfectly. Huge time saver. Many thanks for your help!